# Spell checking LaTeX documents

Tags: tools, spelling, big-list, proofreading

What's the best strategy for spell checking LaTeX documents?

Comment: This question is noticeably lacking in Windows-specific answers. (For those of us using Windows-native editors rather than emacs, vi.) I suspect if I ask a Windows-specific question, it will be merged here... ?

Answer (score 75):

It sort of depends on the system you're working on.

I'm using GNU/Linux and here `aspell` does a good job. For instance, to check `test.tex` in Danish, I would do like this from the terminal:

```
aspell -c -t test.tex -d da
```

The option `-c` tells `aspell` to check the file, `-t` puts it in TeX mode, and `-d` gives the base name of the main dictionary to use.
On Ubuntu/Debian, this can be installed using:

```
sudo aptitude install aspell
```

[Aspell is also available as a Windows executable](http://aspell.net/win32/).  It can but run from the command line or from any good text-editor (i.e. one that supports macros to run external programs).

Comment: You can also use the `--mode=tex` or `-t` options to put aspell into tex mode, which ignores the spelling of standard tex commands.

If you have defined additional tex commands these can be added to or removed from the ignore list using `--add-tex-command=<list>, --rem-tex-command=<list>`.

Comment: Hunspell also has a TeX/LaTeX mode, `-t`, if one is using a language aspell does not support.

Comment: I use this to do a spellcheck in Swedish "aspell --lang=sv --mode=tex -c my_file.tex"

Comment: "Aspell is also available as a Windows executable."
I love that you can [install Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0). This lets you open bash from the Windows command prompt and install and use (a more recent) version of aspell from there. 
Only drawback I've encountered so far, is that bash switches directories if called from a network drive.

Comment: for those who, like me, are struggling with the `--add-tex-command` option: if you want to ignore `\\citep` and `citet` citation commands, just use it's `-add-tex-command "citep op" --add-tex-command "citet op"` (`op` stands for "ignore the optional parameter as well, use "Op" if you do not want to ignore it)

Comment: how can I use aspell with huge latex documents? (Meaning the include other tex files with include or input)

Comment: @Ansa211 Your reading of the manual is incorrect, "op" means skip over an optional parameter and check the next parameter. You can use a whole variation of o, O, p and P. For more detail see  http://aspell.net/man-html/The-Options.html#TeX_002fLaTeX-Filter

Answer (score 35):

**Spell-checking can commonly be handled by your text editor**.  I'm not sure what the windows LaTeX editors have, but it's common to use **vi** or **emacs** in linux, and the editor's spell checking is pretty sufficient.  Also, because these editors are syntax-aware, your spell-checking can be as well.

Comment: I personally use `M-x flyspell-mode` with AucTeX in Emacs which checks spelling as you type.

Comment: As another example, if you use TextMate on Mac OS X to edit your Latex documents, you can use its spell-checking features. Seems to work fairly well.

Comment: Personally use the new `set :spell` in Vim 7, and Automatic Spell Checking available in all system languages in Kile.

Comment: I'd point out that every dedicated TeX editor I know of has a spell checker: this applies to all platforms. It's such an obvious requirement that editors would not really succeed without it.

Answer (score 6):

There's a reasonable on-line spell-checker at [Micro Spell](http://www.microspell.com/fixmytypos.html).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to have a look at the [*spelling* package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spelling).  Though not yet matured, it already works reasonably well.  The *spelling* package requires the LuaTeX engine.  Main features of the package are:

- Text is extracted during typesetting and written to a file that can be checked by your favourite spell-checker application.
- Spelling errors can be highlighted in PDF output.

(The maintainer of the *spelling* package.)

Answer (score 6):

Old question but I figured I'd throw in my two cents.  An approach that I use, following a careful read-through to make sure that I catch as much as I can, is to first convert the latex document to RTF (using the [latex2rtf package](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/)), and then open it up in Word.  The figures tend to be ignored, however the wording and grammar at least can be handled by Word's excellent spelling and grammar checker.

Answer (score 5):

I use a mac and I have [cocoaspell](http://people.ict.usc.edu/~leuski/cocoaspell/), which works for the whole computer. As I use Aquamacs, I then enable flyspell (spell check on the fly), and it is all done!

Answer (score 5):

```
detex doc.tex | spell
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to know, where should I write this command in order to let latex check my spelling? I have tried to write it after \begin{document}, but it doesn´t work. Should I create a new tex file and give this command?

Comment: `detex` is a command line program. It needs to be installed on your system, and you need to run it in a terminal at a command prompt.

Comment: Try `aspell` or `ispell`. May need to be installed with 3rd party package manager.

Answer (score 5):

As other users have advised, `aspell` is a good tool to use for this problem.

However, rather than configuring `aspell`'s behaviour at the command line with `--add-tex-command=<list>`, `--rem-tex-command=<list>`, etc. I'd recommend creating project-level `tex_conf` and `my_spelling` files. These files are easier to manage and curate for larger projects and can also be version controlled (hopefully with the rest of your project files) and distributed with your content.

Typically, in my projects I would provision a simple shell script (`check_spellings.sh`):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

aspell -c -t *.tex --conf=./tex_conf --add-extra-dicts=./my_spelling
```

In this example I'm checking all files in the executed directory with a `.tex` file extension. I also have a file `tex_conf` and `my_spelling` in the same directory as my `.tex` files. (You may organise your project as you see fit so long as you adjust the paths to `tex_conf`, `my_spelling`, and the targeted `.tex` files in `check_spellings.sh`)

`tex_conf` is the place to add and remove tex commands for checking. An example `tex_conf` may contain:

```
add-tex-command cref p
add-tex-command captionsetup op
add-tex-command begin pop
add-tex-command frac pp
```

From the aspell documentation:

> A ’p’ skips over a parameter while a ’P’ doesn’t. Similarly an ’o’
> will skip over an optional parameter while an ’O’ doesn’t. The first
> letter on the list will apply to the first parameter, the second
> letter will apply to the second parameter etc

An example `my_spelling` may look like:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 1
AIC
Akaike
autocorrelation
HMC
Stanislaw
```

Comment: Good summary.  Is there any equivalent of `add-tex-environment` to help us ignore arguments of environments?

Answer (score 4):

It depends not only on the packages suggested but also on the language that you are using and on the front-end you edit your text. If you are a Windows user, I recommend [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) which is a paid front-end for LaTeX. It has [dictionaries for many languages](http://www.winedt.org/Dict/) and underlines in red the words which are written incorrectly. A right click on an underlined word shows alternatives for it. If you write in different languages, you can also combine different dictionaries.

[image: Example of Winedt spell checking]

If you problem is hyphenation, however, remember to configure MiKTeX and your document for the language considered. There may be problems still, but you can correct them manually with `\hyphenation`.

Answer (score 4):

I have good experiences with the spell checker of [TeXStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/), but I guess there are many other editors with good LaTeX compatible spell checkers. You find a good list in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

A second option that some of my colleagues practice is to copy'n'paste the pdf output to Word. This may sound cumbersome and probably is, but the time you will/should take to proof read your document will exceed the time amount for the copy and paste by order of magnitudes.

Comment: It is time consuming way to paste in word, but it worth because the office 2013 can check some grammar errors not only the spells.

Answer (score 4):

The [`check_spelling`](https://github.com/HughParsonage/TeXCheckR/blob/master/R/check_spelling.R) command from my R package [`TeXCheckR`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=TeXCheckR) is designed to enhance the features in `hunspell`.

**Synopsis:**

```
library(TeXCheckR)
check_spelling("file-to-check.tex")
```

**Features:**

- Ignores the contents of commands which don't print, for example the contents of `\label`s and cite commands, which hunspell spuriously raises as possible spelling errors. You can also add commands whose contents will be ignored.
- The ability to add words to the dictionary on a document-by-document basis, by adding 
  `% add_to_dictionary: stackexchange`
  to the preamble.
- The ability to fail on certain words, to maintain consistency
  `% stop_if_present: organize`
- The ability to detect acronyms and add them automatically to the dictionary, so the following will pass.

  > The Quebec Xylophone Enterprise Foundation (QXEF) is fictional.
- Author names in the bibliography are automatically added (with a note).
- Valid English contractions are not considered spelling errors.
- The contents of `\input` and `\include` files are checked recursively.

<sup>Due to an oversight, I check against the `en_GB` dictionary and don't provide the user to select a dictionary. In the next version, I'll allow any hunspell dictionary. (It's trivial to update this: just don't want to pester CRAN.)</sup>

Comment: Consistently ignored in the requests and answers regarding spell checkers is the fact that spell checking is not enough.  Syntax checking (and good proofreading) is also necessary.  Evidence:  a correctly spelled, but quite erroneous notice posted on a (physical, not electronic) Stanford bulletin board some years ago: "The semester will being on September 4."

Answer (score 3):

As it hasn't been mentioned, note also [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html):

[image: test.png]

Cross-platform (on Linux I use 4.1.1 as it is the last static build available for download, otherwise my OS is too old), apparently it has it's own spell-check dictionaries (program directory contains e.g. `en_GB.aff`, `en_GB.dic` - not sure if these use `aspell` or standalone engine); comments are skipped (I like), commands are skipped (I like), filecontents with bibliography entries are skipped (surprised at this, like), math is skipped (like) -- though some packages/arguments are still checked/underlined, and `\cite` arguments too (see [Make spellchecker ignore contents of certain commands in TexMaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62646/make-spellchecker-ignore-contents-of-certain-commands-in-texmaker)). In any case, this looks quite good to me...

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, here is what I have found to work well if you have access to Word. It is similar to [the suggestion of espais](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212510/1078). `pdflatex` the document and then open the PDF in Word (which Word 2013 can do).

When proof-reading a document what I am looking for are not just spelling mistakes but more broadly *typos*; for example repeated words (e.g., "the the"). Word is actually quite good at catching these mistakes.

The only minor problem I have found is that certain types of formatting can confuse Word's conversion from PDF. For instance watermarks caused problems (but in my case they were easy to turn off).

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment on the text editor question:

I made good experiences using the [`LTeX` extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=valentjn.vscode-ltex) in vscode. It also checks for grammar. And I tested: It works equally well on Windows and Linux.

Other spell checking extensions also support LaTeX.
As pointed out above by @machinaut, every decent text editor should.

Comment: +1 nice answer, I have edited your question to add a link to the `LTeX` documentation, hope this is fine

Comment: Sure is, thank you. I though most people would search thorugh vscode anyway, but good idea, in case the extension disappears for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the best tool on the market is [GNU aspell](http://aspell.net/) and it supports TeX. However, it's very difficult to configure it right. I made my own [texsc](https://github.com/yegor256/texsc) tool to simplify the usage of aspell. You just do this and your LaTeX documents will be checked:

```
gem install texsc
texsc --ignore=citet,citep,verbatim book.tex chapter1.tex chapter2.tex
```

You can also specify your own additional vocabulary:

```
texsc --pws=vocab.pws book.tex
```

More info in [this blog post](https://www.yegor256.com/2020/10/06/latex-spell-checking.html) of mine.

Comment: Is it possible to use GNU Aspell for LaTeX on Windows? If so, how could I be doing this?

Comment: @lucenalex I believe it's possible. Try it out and if something doesn't work, submit a ticket [here](https://github.com/yegor256/texsc/issues), I will try to help.

Comment: @lucenalex not sure if you've been helped with this, but I have it working. I downloaded the WSL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 1):

I usually arrange my LaTeX documents into multiple chapters and sections, sometimes in a directory tree.  For a global spellcheck, I use a command like

```
find . -name "*.tex" -exec hunspell -t -d en_US -l {} \; | sort -n | uniq -c
```

This works directly in unix-like environments, but could be arranged to work under any OS.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [machinaut's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29/84495)...  In `vim` [version 7+](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/using-spell-checking-vim/), you can enable spell check by entering (in command mode)

```
:set spell spelllang=en_us
```

To turn it off

```
:set nospell
```

For additional documentation, search for the `spell.txt` file.  On my Mac (OSX 10.15.7), it is located at `/usr/share/vim/vim81//doc/spell.txt`.  Look in `/usr/share/vim//vim81/spell` for available languages.

It looks like you can get additional languages from [here](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/). Look at [Christian Brabandt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5654/22014) for further details on installation of new languages.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using VS Code, you can install the [LTeX – LanguageTool grammar/spell checkin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=valentjn.vscode-ltex) which calls [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) behind the scenes.

As standalone UI there is [TeXtidote](https://github.com/sylvainhalle/textidote) available.