# Grammar-checking tool for use with LaTeX?

Tags: linux, spelling, grammar, proofreading

I am looking for a grammar-checking tool, i.e., something that checks for mistakes such as "two dog" or "a books".  It has to work on Linux (Ubuntu).  Also, since I use macros to generate some of the prose, it has to somehow work with LaTeX.  I don't think that such checkers are LaTeX-aware, so it has to work with some compilation product of LaTeX: DVI or PDF.

If you suggest a grammar checker that checks plain text, please explain how to you extract the text.  catdvi does a nice job, but it leaves some garbage like page numbers.

Comment: [TextLint](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/textlint) is not a grammar checker, but might still be of interest. It's a writing style checker, meaning it will recognize things like passive voice, repetitions, useless words...

Comment: A good alarm:
I have to think twice before I move to Latex. Since I am second language speaker to English,I found the grammar suggestions in MS word so helpful. I like the fonts and the flexibility  Latex offers, and I was thinking to migrate to it(I am writing my mater thesis, by the way). May be I have to stick with MS Word... 

Thanks

Comment: obbsss I wrote "mater" in place of "master". Well, Andrew Roberts could be right " it(Ms word) corrects the common typos that we all make. However, the problem in my opinion is that it means we don't learn from our mistakes, e.g., you will continue to type 'teh' instead of 'the' because Word will sort it out for you"

hahahhaa

Comment: Since this is asked in 2010, I wonder if there is any update. Could OP consider remove the check mark to encourage more answers? The current answer is still unsatisfactory, leading me to always write in MS Word first then do formatting in Latex.

Comment: @Anh I'm still unaware of a good solution other than hacking the LaTeX code into plain text and then running this or the other grammar checker on it, so AFAIK the answer is still valid. If you have a specific situation you're facing, or have other language tools in mind, I think you should post a new question.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Did you try the LyX-GC web app? It is tailored to TeX.

Comment: `latex2html` and then upload to [grammarly.com](http://www.grammarly.com). Note that this is a commercial product. A restricted trial period is available which permits free evaluation of the product for non-commercial purposes only for a limited period of time.

Comment: [here](https://qr.ae/TUtgNQ) I have also tried to list all the Free and Open Source writing assistance tools I could find.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org/) is a very nice standalone, Java-based grammar checker.  However, it works on plain text.  Therefore, I needed to convert my LaTeX document to as plain as possible text document - Not a simple task.  I managed to do it using the following trick:

1. I arranged for all floats to hold their positions using the floats package and the H option.  This is required so that captions won't break the paragraphs when transforming to plain text.
2. I removed line numbers using the nopageno package.
3. I used a sed script to do some more fine-tuning, like adding periods to section names and description labels.  I don't publish the script here, since that it is really specific to my-own style and conventions.
4. After this preprocessing, I compiled to DVI and ran `catdvi -s`.
5. I used another simple sed script to get rid of empty lines and page breaks.  The final result is a reasonable textual conversion of the LaTeX document, which LanguageTool can work on.

There are still some leftover annoyances, like inlined program listings, which the grammar checker can't understand, but all together I got a decent automated proof-checking from it :)

Comment: You can transform your TeX document to plain text using `detex` on the command line. This doesn’t work perfectly but probably well enough for your purpose.

Comment: I tried detex.  It just leaves out the macros, which is not the same thing as rendering the document to plain text after macro expansion

Comment: I have a LaTeX-to-HTML conversion set up using tex4ht. Copying the converted HTML from the browser to the LanguageTool online spell checker worked fine for me.

Comment: It is perfectly polite and recommended to answer your own question. It's even in the help center!

Comment: [LanguageTools](http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool) is now included in [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#features).

Comment: A pretty basic preprocess can be done with e.g. `pdftotext -enc ASCII7 main.pdf`.  To get the command line version of LanguageTool to ignore some of its rules, use the `-d` flag, e.g. `java -jar languagetool-commandline.jar -l en-GB -d "EN_QUOTES" main.txt`.

Comment: Today I discovered there is an emacs mode of languagetool called [langtool.el](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-langtool) that basically interfaces with the java files. If you use Auctex you could give it a shot. I cannot test it now and I'm sure I will forget to write this comment if I go for a test tomorrow. So I put it here!

Comment: At least 52 people are happy that you are not "polite". :)

Comment: Unfortunately, in stackoverflow where people are more stressed than here, people are eager to close questions, preferably without reading (e.g., downvoting in a fraction of a second after posted), and specially if it is an answer to your own question, even with the clear official recommendation to provide such kind of answer. Useless competition for rep is an illness

Answer (score 28):

I wrote a grammar checker for checking TeX documents called [LyX-GC](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX-GrammarChecker). It can also be used online as a [web app](http://mccabedj.ucc.asn.au/checktex.html).

It can use LanguageTool as a back-end. The main advantages over just using LanguageTool directly are that (1) it filters the TeX to avoid false positives from LanguageTool trying to interpret TeX commands as English and (2) it has hundreds of is own rules, including TeX-specific rules. For example, it knows that "`See \ref{lem:foo}`" should really be "`See Lemma \ref{lem:foo}`". (Also, if you use [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/), LyX-GC obviously has the advantage of being able to integrate with LyX.)

LyX-GC only really supports English (though there is experimental French support in the git repository).

Comment: It seems that the web app does not work now.

Comment: Somehow the irony of a grammar checker printing out the phrase "Captial without preceeding fullstop" at the end of a long day gave me a good chuckle (I think the words are capital and preceding). Nevertheless a good enough tool :)

Comment: @therealrootuser Well, now you know why I needed to write myself a grammar checker. ;)

Comment: Great tool, thank you!

Comment: Does this still work? Not sure how to set up in Lyx now in 2021

Comment: @AimForClarity I think so, but I haven't used it for a couple of years. What distro are you using?

Answer (score 22):

I've just finished writing a new tool for checking spelling and grammar directly on LaTeX files, called **TeXtidote**:

https://sylvainhalle.github.io/textidote

The program can remove markup from the file and send it to the Language Tool library, which performs a verification of both spelling and grammar in a dozen languages. What is unique to TeXtidote is that it keeps track of the relative position of words between the original and the "clean" text. This means that it can translate the messages from Language Tool back to their proper location directly in your source file. By default, TeXtidote produces an HTML report that shows your original sources, with the errors found by Language Tool highlighted at the correct location:

[image: Screenshot]

The tool is free and easy to install (OS-independent, requires Java). I encourage you to give it a try and tell me what you think! (More information about download/install/use can be found on the Readme page of the GitHub repository; click on the "Download" button on the web site to get there.)

Comment: It would help to have some integration guidance E.G using TeXworks ((as supplied default OOB with both main distros) that would guide other editor users. In MiKTeX TeXworks it is easy to add in the "Typeset" choices an entry "GrammarChecker" that can run a simple shell script (e.g. grammar.cmd) that in turn can have a line or two (or more) e.g. h:\java\bin\java.exe -jar h:\texidote\textidote.jar --html %1 >report.html **and on the second line** report.html **will automatically open in default browser**. P.S I don't see the red mark up whats needed to invoke  Language Tool library

Comment: My bad omitted the --clean en  variables in my script so it calls lang tools (another reason to spoon feed a script template for noobs like me :-)

Comment: I'm really digging the Plain Text mode. NOW to see if this could work with ALE and Vim.

Comment: I downloaded the example.tex file but the instructions after that are unclear. Am I supposed to type "java -jar textidote.jar --output html example.tex > report.html" in the Run app? If I do that, nothing happens though.

Comment: I found the tool very interesting, but not being able to install it. Is it compatible with windows, for example? Is there a video tutorial showing the installation step by step?

Answer (score 14):

I don't believe there are good grammar checkers, but Word's is better than most — provided, that is, you tell it to switch off broken features like checking for passive constructions.

You can load your Latex file into Word as a plain text file and look for the highlights that indicates that its grammar checker is concerned about some construction (typically green dotted underlining).

With a bit of macrology, you can get a good approximation to indicating to Word which bits are English (or whatever) and indicate the Latex markup as not-a-language.  This makes running the grammar/spell checkers more pleasant to use.

**Postscript** — I had not noticed the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag: various flavours of Word *can* be run under Wine.  In the absence of competition, this might be the best Linux solution, although it can't be the best free software solution.

Comment: Rather than loading your `.tex` files as text, you could try and convert it into HTML, and loading the result through Word that way. Unfortunately that means you have to try and find a good LaTeX to HTML converter, which is something I can't find...

Comment: And another option is available if your build process creates `.ps` (PostScript) files; you can use `ps2ascii` to translate the TeX'd output into text and play with it from there, but unfortunately this includes headers, footers and hyphenation.

Comment: @jevon: *convert it into HTML* Sure, I give a script to do this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/convert-tex-to-non-tex-and-back/16406#16406 which has problems (it doesn't tell Word which is text and macros).  *ps2ascii* - These conversions are more trouble than they are worth, and in particular, the round trip loses most Tex formatting.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, doesn't that script only convert TeX into HTML-highlighted TeX, and doesn't actually compile it? e.g. `\textbf{}` won't become bold text in the generated HTML. I since wrote a basic script in PHP to actually compile TeX into HTML, I might release it later.

Comment: @jevon: The HTML-highlighting does appropriately display things like italics, bold and so on, and also gives section heads or subscripts in larger or smaller fonts.  I don't think compiling the Tex is actually desirable at the editing stage, because of the problem of translating changes to the output back to the Tex source; if you really do want to do this, tex4ht gives a good framework for this.

Answer (score 11):

> ## VIM-BASED SOLUTIONS

## INTRODUCTION

[LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org/) is a blessing for the open-source community when it comes to spelling & grammar checking. As a bonus, it is a platform independent Java (.jar) application. Be warned, it is not perfect yet, but it is definitely usable and fills a gap that existed for a very long time. It is being actively developed and I sincerely hope for the day it will be the best tool available ever.

To begin with, any grammar-check solution will inevitably use LanguageTool. It is almost inescapable -- even paid commercial utilities will not give you the flexibility and the integration offered by LanguageTool. Now given this fact, the question simplifies to asking:

> How can I use LanguageTool on platform X for documents of type Y?

I will now proceed to answering it for the **VIM** platform (and latex documents as just a special case). This is a canonical case as far as linux OS is concerned.

## Basic Set-up

In summary, as of today in the Feb'17, I find three *usable* solutions as three plugins. I usually recommend Vundle plugin manager whose simple syntax to include in .vimrc is: (No harm in having all three plugins simultaneously. The subsequent setup of each individual plugin is mentioned in the rest of the write up.)

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'dpelle/vim-LanguageTool'
Plugin 'rhysd/vim-grammarous'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
call vundle#end()
```

And then from within vim, issue a pair of commands once-for-all:

```
:so $MYVIMRC
:VundleInstall
```

You also need LanguageTool main java (.jar) application installed to `~/LanguageTool/`. You may use the following:

```
>> mkdir -p ~/LanguageTool
>> cd ~/LanguageTool
>> wget https://www.languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-3.6.zip -O LT.zip
>> unzip LT.zip
```

## The Main Solutions

### 1. Plugin: [vim-LanguageTool](https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool)

As being the earliest LanguageTool plugin, this has some impressive performance except for some uncomfortable navigation.

There is one caveat to link the LanguageTool application on your desktop.
Include the following line in your `.vimrc` and restart vim (you may `:so $MYVIMRC` too).

```
let g:languagetool_jar='~/LanguageTool/languagetool-commandline.jar'
```

All set, you only have to start the spell/grammar-check-session using command `:LanguageToolCheck` and end the session using `:LanguageToolReset`. What you do in between is the key, and you use two commands `:lnext` `:lprevious` to navigate among errors. You may remap them in `.vimrc` for a better comfort for e.g.

```
nmap gn :lnext<CR>
nmap gp :lprevious<CR>
```

Actually, you can be slightly smarter and try using those maps only when `LanguageToolCheck` is active. And `nunmap` them immediately on issuing `LanguageToolReset`. (I found aliases LTC and LTR nice, issuing these additional nmap/nunmap'ing commands)

You are also allowed to change color of each type of error (for e.g. green for grammar and red for spelling) using vim commands such as: `hi LanguageToolGrammarError guibg=peru guifg=wheat`. The full list of types of errors is found in `:h LanguageTool`.

### 2. Plugin: [vim-grammarous](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous)

This is actually a nice alternative to the one above. It automatically installs languagetool java application for itself on its first invocation, hence a much quicker and easier installation to get yourself going.

So directly coming to the usage which is very similar to above except for a couple of more commands. Use `:GrammarousCheck` to start and `:GrammarousReset` to end the spell/grammar-check-session. The main tasks are in between and are performed using the small window that opens up explaining the errors in the file. This new window is special and using commands `f`, `n`, `p`, and `?` you can navigate.

I personally prefer some of the [remaps](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous/issues/34) as below for a more comfortable usage.

```
let g:grammarous#hooks = {}
function! g:grammarous#hooks.on_check(errs) abort
    nmap <buffer>gn <Plug>(grammarous-move-to-next-error)
    nmap <buffer>gp <Plug>(grammarous-move-to-previous-error)
    nmap <buffer>gr <Plug>(grammarous-move-to-info-window)r
    nmap <buffer>gas f <Plug>(grammarous-move-to-info-window)f
    nmap <buffer>gR <Plug>(grammarous-move-to-info-window)R
endfunction
function! g:grammarous#hooks.on_reset(errs) abort
    nunmap <buffer>gn
    nunmap <buffer>gp
    nunmap <buffer>gr
    nunmap <buffer>gf
    nunmap <buffer>gR
endfunction
```

This above sample, when present in your `.vimrc` will create five handy additional normal-mode commands namely `gn` (next error), `gp` (previous error), `gr` (ignore the error), `gf` (fix automatically with suggested correction), `gR` (ignore all errors with same rule). These are available only to the current buffer and only when `:GrammarousCheck` is active, and will disappear as soon as `:GrammarousReset` is used.

### 3. Python wrappper: [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check) in combination with vim's [Syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) plugin

Note: syntastic should have been installed already during above *Basic Set-up* step of three plugins.

This is an interesting and simplest solution of all, if you already have the infamous Syntastic plugin on vim and python installed on your linux. All that you have to do is install the python-wrapper [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check) using the terminal-command:

```
>> pip install --upgrade language-check
```

and add the following two lines to `.vimrc`.

```
let g:syntastic_text_checkers = ['language_check']
let g:syntastic_tex_checkers = ["lacheck", "chktex", "text/language_check"]
let g:syntastic_text_language_check_args = '--language=en-GB'
let g:syntastic_tex_language_check_args = '--language=en-GB'
```

Caveat: By default, this setup checks for spelling everytime a save/write command `:w` is used and therefore *slows it down*. You may disable this check-on-write by using the following line in `.vimrc`. But note that it means that you will check grammar yourself manually.

```
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

All set, you can simply use two commands `:SyntasticCheck` and `:SyntasticReset` to start and end the session respectively. You don't need any more commands here because of the special interface that already highlights and explains on status bar of what went wrong, as you move your cursor to the specific locations.

If anything troubling, you may first want to verify whether the filetype is properly detected to either `tex` or `text` by using the command:

```
:SyntasticInfo
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two old Unix tools for checking grammar. They are called style and diction. Check out the link:

http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_15.html#SEC220

I personally have never used them.

However I am of a belief that the best way to check your punctuation and grammar is to have somebody else proofread your paper for you.

Answer (score 8):

The [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) editor has integrated spell-check and it works on Linux too.

I think it uses the same spell-checker as OpenOffice, so it should be able to check the mentioned mistakes.

Comment: You can elaborate a little on this. For example, you can compile your documents (use draft mode) and start a spell check in the pdf-view. Then you can copy and paste the output as a pure text into a grammar checker. Of course, it is not possibility to automatically correct the misspellings and wrong grammar with a mouse click. You have to correct the language manually in the TeX source (not a big issue, in my opnion).

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked out [stylecheck](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nspring/software/style-check-readme.html)? I found it to be reasonably good, though I'm not sure what it does with macros....

Answer (score 5):

I've been thinking about this lately as well. The question [How to perform advanced spell checking of latex documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-perform-advanced-spell-checking-of-latex-documents) suggests a tool called [After the Deadline](http://www.afterthedeadline.com/) which looks quite interesting. Haven't tried it though so I can't tell you how to use it or if it's any good.

EDIT: Don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but I've been testing their web service and it's not too impressive. It reports no errors on these sentences: "I have two dog. I read a books"

Comment: It is not so good.

Answer (score 5):

I add [Queequeg](http://queequeg.sourceforge.net/index-e.html) to the list, although it is far from perfect, too. It is a simple command-line tool aimed exactly at finding concordance errors in English. It works with LaTeX sources out of the box.

Unlike After the Deadline, it errs on the side of false positives, and sometimes there are a *lot* of them. It correctly reports the concordance errors on the example sentence "I have two dog; I read a books" suggested in another answer.

(Small tip for those who wish to try it: there is an error in the installation instructions, you should replace `make dict WORDNET=/src/wordnet/dict` with `make dict WORDNETDICT=/src/wordnet/dict`.)

Comment: Oh, the irony: I just ran it on my own answer here above and I found that I had forgotten the "s" in "reports". :)

Answer (score 5):

When opening LaTeX files with `vim` text editor, it is possible to use a [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3223) that integrates `LanguageTool` grammar checker.  Since, it does not explicitly support the LaTeX syntax, some elements will be detected as syntax errors.

However, the number of these false positives can be significantly reduced if the most common errors due to LaTeX syntax are ignored. This can be achieved, adding, for instance, the following line to `~/.vimrc`,

`let g:languagetool_disable_rules='WHITESPACE_RULE,EN_QUOTES,'
    \ . 'COMMA_PARENTHESIS_WHITESPACE,CURRENCY,EN_UNPAIRED_BRACKETS'`

While not perfect, this approach allows for the LaTeX document to be checked, without the hassle of converting it to a plain text format.

Comment: Note: you can also use [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check) (integrating with LanguageTool) and [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/syntax_checkers/text/language_check.vim).

Comment: I'd recommend against disabling these rules. You may miss a real mistake this way.

Comment: @varepsilon True, though my experience of it was that without disabling those you get a lot of false positives, and so it becomes more difficult not to miss actual errors.

Answer (score 5):

I was using TexWorks and had the exact same problem.
Upon investigation which platforms were supported by LanguageTool, I discovered [TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/), which full integrates with LanguateTool and works perfectly.
See this page for integration details: http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool#toc4

Answer (score 5):

For Visusal Studio code, the [LTeX – LanguageTool grammar/spell checking](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=valentjn.vscode-ltex) does a great job for both LaTeX and Markdown files.

[image: Screenshot LTeX]

Answer (score 4):

It's also an option to spell-check the output, i.e. the PDF file. It's a bit indirect, but at least you won't have problems with the LaTeX specific syntax.

Adobe Acrobat has a spell-check if I'm not mistaken, but not everybody has access to it of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SCaVis](http://jwork.org/scavis) editor  to edit Latex files. It has LaTeX tools (to insert math characters), content management (shows Latex sections on the left panel), LaTeX syntax highlighting and spell checking based on OpenOffice dictionaries

Comment: It's unfortunate that there's no mention of it supporting LaTeX syntax on the main page (only other programming environments). It's only hidden in the section on [Writing Jython/Python script in the SCaVis IDE](http://jwork.org/scavis/wikidoc/doku.php?id=man:general:working_with_ide&#writing_jython_python_script_in_the_scavis_ide), where it is just as inconspicuous.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use grammar and style checking using the [RTextDoc](http://jwork.org/rtextdoc) LaTeX editor.

Comment: Payment required (for actual software).

Answer (score 3):

[HEVEA](http://hevea.inria.fr/) is a Latex to HTML translator that does not insert line breaks (unlike detex) and can handle most environments, such as tables, that may include text you also want to grammar-check.
Since you are using Ubuntu, you can install the package `hevea`.
Then, you can translate your latex project with the command

```
hevea document.tex
```

Since Hevea uses its own parsers and library implementations, it will not understand some Latex environments.
In my case, I had to "comment out" all `\begin{tabulary}...\end{tabulary}` environments by enclosing them with

```
\begin{latexonly}
\begin{tabulary}
...
\end{tabulary}
\end{latexonly}
```

The `latexonly` environment is available after adding `\usepackage{hevea}` to the preamble of your Latex document and only instructs Hevea to ignore its contents and not affect your usual Latex workflow.

Essentially, this reduces the problem to grammar-checking an html page, `document.html`.

The good thing about html is that word-processing software, which tend to have state-of-the-art spelling and grammar checking, can flawlessly import html pages. I made good experience using Microsoft Word 2010, which is good at checking English grammar.
Aside from many false positives in math expressions, it found several subtle grammar mistakes I had not found after proof-reading my thesis twice.
Note that MS [Word 2010 runs under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22248) environments.
Concerning native spell checking on Linux and Ubuntu, you can use LibreOffice.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think a list of commands/environments to ignore would be a good idea. Would save a lot of adding `latexonly` environments.

Answer (score 2):

As somebody said before,  RTextDoc http://jwork.org/rtextdoc/  is a good editor for LaTex source code. It has on-the-fly syntax highlighting of errors (red line) and problems with the grammar (blue lines).  See the  image shown below:

[image: RTextDoc editor with grammar checks]

It's powered by the LanguageTools. In addition to grammar checks, it has many 'bells and whistles'  for the usual LaTeX source editing. 
Note that the grammar checking and syntax highlighting works fine even without activation to the Pro version. It also runs equally well on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: There's something sinister about RTextDoc: for the "full" version, it asks you to become a member, demands your phone number, address, and -- if you want to avoid payment -- to provide a code. But nowhere that I can see does the site say what the cost is!

Answer (score 2):

I just published a 480 page book and found a great grammar check that also preserves the embedded tex commands. 
1. Rename your .tex files to .txt
2. Open the .txt file in MS Word (as simple text) and perform the grammar check. It is easy to simply skip over the embedded LaTex commands. Make the needed changes and save the file. 
3. Rename the .txt file as .tex
4. Now you can continue editing your .tex file as usual.

Comment: But OP uses macros to generate text, so you would need to deal with something like `\def\noun{book}one \noun\ is ok, two \noun\ is bad`.  For example, [OP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6552/107497) goes to a lot of trouble to expand the macros.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a post on the solutions that I found, on [medium](https://echo-bravo-fox.medium.com/grammar-checkers-for-pdf-and-latex-436fcae4ed3a).
The various options tried (April 2022) are:

- TeXstudio and LanguageTool.
- Textidote.
- YaLafi.
- Overleaf and LanguageTool plugin.
- Overleaf and Grammarly plugin and textarea plugin (not recommended, a bit unstable).
- Overleaf and Writefull plugin.

Some other programs, that can be found in this thread, have not been included.

Comment: Why don't you recommend Grammarly?

Comment: Because it needs 2 plugin to work on Overleaf, often throwing errors. Answer improved.

Comment: Thank you! I don't use Grammarly on Overleaf but I use it elsewhere and I was curious.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool

You can convert your LaTex file to HTML and check the HTML with the LanguageTool.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution i found out: [Latex Spelling and Grammar Check](http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/guides/spell-grammar-latex.html). Check it out and let me know what you are thinking of it.

Comment: This is a very low effort answer. This tiny guide could very well fit in the answer instead of just posting a link. Also, using aspell and microsoft word is not revolutionary.

Comment: You have a point. Should i delete it and post it as a comment?

Comment: I think you should at least edit your answer to include the names of the tools, if not writing out the whole guide as the answer. Please ignore my comment on it not being revolutionary - noone have made the same suggestion, so it might very well be useful for some.

Answer (score 0):

There are superb grammar checking solutions for Microsoft Word. Open the PDF file using MS Word. This is done in Windows by using right click, then "open with" and select Microsoft Word. The generated Word document may contain a few errors with hyphenated words and footnotes, but it is useful.

MS Word spell checker may be complemented with a popular grammar checking tool such as Grammarly, Language Tool, ProWritingAid.

Answer (score 0):

The AbiWord project includes a US English-only grammar checking plugin using "Link Grammar." (For Linux) Current version seems to be 3.02 (from 2016.)
I've found it useful, however, I haven't found a way to turn off its detection of certain formatting problems, such as hard returns (from the days of the typewriter, remember, before word wrap?) I suppose running text through something like Sigil or Calibre's epub editor might be able to fix that first. The last time I tried, I may have done something wrong, and it removed ALL spaces, however! That pretty much made the text unreadable.

Edit: Link Grammar Parser
January, 2019: link-grammar 5.6.0 released!
 https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/

Comment: Assuming that "Abiword" can perform grammar checking on plain text, how do you propose we do some preprocessing to remove the "tex" commands from the tex file before it can be fed? For example see @Little Bobby Tables 's answer where it is mentioned how to segregate the plain text for use.

Answer (score 0):

The filtering tool [YaLafi](https://github.com/matze-dd/YaLafi) provides LaTeX filtering with character position mapping between LaTeX and extracted plain text.
On the project page, an application for integration with the proofreading software [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org) is proposed.
Among others, it can generate a report in text or HTML format.

The filter does recognise LaTeX definitions of the form \newcommand in the input text, and it can be additionally adapted with some Python statements.
For instance, the input

```
\newcommand\xxx A
\newcommand\yyy{books}
\xxx\ \yyy{} are interesting.
```

will produce a complaint about 'A books' in line 3.

Alternatives are [TeXtidote](https://github.com/sylvainhalle/textidote)
and [vscode-ltex](https://github.com/valentjn/vscode-ltex),
but both do not process macro definitions.
[Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) recognises own macros, but does not perform character position mapping.

YaLafi is still in an early stage and may be difficult to install if one is not acquainted with Python.