# Is it possible to take a paper from LaTeX to Word and back again? (a hobbit's tale...)

Tags: msword

I'm an academic editor and I get this question at least a few times a year. The answer I have to give: I have no idea but I THINK it's possible? I'm reluctant to mess around with anyone's files so I've never dared try it myself. Word is the only program I can edit in (it is the ONLY program that allows for tracked/visible, large-scale, developmental edits, trust me... I've tried everything). Does anyone have experience taking a paper they've written in LaTeX, pasting it into MS Word (I'm willing to ignore all the wonky code spots as long as I can still see the actual text/writing okay), and then pasting it back into LaTeX? Is it as simple as what I just described (copy and paste)? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The answer: it depends.  I've had a paper converted from a LaTeX-generated PDF file to Word, and it was really a disaster -- *don't do it that way*!  On the other hand, it's been suggested that converting from LaTeX source to "rich text format" may be much more successful; I have no direct experience with that, nor with conversion back to LaTeX.  But I think there are other questions here that deal with the problem.  Good luck.

Comment: [conversion - How can I convert from Microsoft Word to a LaTeX document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document) / [conversion - Convert TeX to non-TeX and back - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16367/convert-tex-to-non-tex-and-back?noredirect=1&lq=1) / [conversion - Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

Comment: By the way, it's certainly possible to convert LaTeX to word as a list of pages each page consist of an image that is the LaTeX page, then "add text box" to "modify" text etc.. That way cannot convert back though except also as image, but then it's quite useless

Comment: You definitely shouldn't do it by copy and paste. Try [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or one of the other suggestions in the links above. (And although I think I'm wasting my breath, because of how good the large companies are at tricking people into lock in, but I'm a journal editor too, and a combination of git and LaTeX can *most definitely* handle "tracked/visible, large-scale, developmental edits", though it's a very different workflow.)