# Texshop grammatic correction

Tags: texshop, grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grammar-checking tool for use with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex)

As a non-native English speaker, I would like to know if there is a grammar correction software available for [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/) (Mac OS). While working with Word it is useful when, regardless of the spelling correction, it helps you with missing articles and paragraphing issues (position of verbs and nouns or non-trivial punctuation).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, TeXShop uses the built-in spell checker of OS X. Alternatively, you can use [cocoAspell or Excalibur](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/links.html). However, none of these solutions support grammar checks.

Comment: texShop does not see built-in spell checker of OS X for grammer. @hakaze