# tool for checking my scientific writing for common style errors

Tags: tools, proofreading

I write frequently scientific reports such as technical reports, research papers, book chapters etc. I use LaTeX for writing these reports.

My question is "Is there any tool with latex support, which can check my scientific writing for common style errors?"

Please assume that I am comfortable with Windows/unix OS.

Comment: Are you looking for a debugging tool?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "style errors"? Do you have grammar, syntax, and orthography in mind, or are you referring to matters of LaTeX vs Plain TeX style, say?

Comment: Many Many thanks Mico. As you said, I have grammar, syntax, and orthography in my mind for "style errors".

Comment: a bit of googling gives some suggestions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex , http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX-GrammarChecker , http://people.engr.ncsu.edu/txie/publications/writingtools.html , and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents?rq=1 which shows up in the "related documents" list

Comment: There are GNU `style` and `diction`: http://www.gnu.org/software/diction/diction.html "Diction and style are two old standard Unix commands. Diction identifies wordy and commonly misused phrases. Style analyses surface characteristics of a document, including sentence length and other readability measures." You would have to use something like deTeX to make them TeX-aware though.

Answer (score 1):

For [Grammar check](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6333/15717). 
For syntax, use [syntonly](http://texblog.org/2011/02/02/check-syntax-only-save-time-typesetting/) package available at [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/syntonly) 
For [Spell check](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15/15717).

For scientific documents, its always better to do proofreading yourself or with someone who is aware of the domain. None of the software can match it.

PS: Check [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/search/) and this site for other type of latex tools/packages.