# Are there any editors or packages with auto-correct for LaTeX commands?

Tags: editors

When a LaTeX command is written incorrectly, the document does not compile and the workflow is interrupted. In most cases, this is due to a typo, such as writing `\foornote{}` instead of `footnote{}`.

Are there any editors that use an auto-correct for situations like this?

The algorithm for doing the auto-correct, I guess, would be similar to the auto-correct for spelling as found in MS Word, which changes things like `neccessary` to `necessary` on-the-fly without users even noticing.

Comment: Take a look at faq Q's [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/15717) and choose yours.

Comment: @texenthusiast The list doesn't specify the feature I'm looking for, and researching each one would be a considerable task. (Note, at this point, I'm not sure the feature exists at all).

Comment: May be you are right, see [syntax checking package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78854/15717) `\usepackage{syntonly} 
\syntaxonly`

Comment: In vim, you can use `:imap` or `IMAP(..)` (the latter is part of vim-latex-suite) to do auto-correct on the fly (but you'll have to build the database of auto-correction yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeXstudio ([Sourceforge](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) / [tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5281/4012)) doesn’t have autocorrect (built in, cf. [Qrrbrbirlbel’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110534/are-there-any-editors-or-packages-with-auto-correct-for-latex-commands/110538?noredirect=1#comment242905_110538)), but it marks unrecognized macros with a red background:

[image: unrecognized macro highlighting]
<sup>`\foornote` vs. `\footnote`</sup>

In order for this to make sense, TeXstudio notices which packages you are using and automatically tries to determine which macros are defined by them, mostly sucessfully so (if it should fail, you could complement macros manually):

[image: with lipsum loaded] [image: without lipsum loaded]
<sup>`lipsum` loaded vs. `lipsum` not loaded</sup>

However, when you’re using TeXstudio (or just about any editor with decent auto*completion*, you’re not going to need this too often because `\footnote` will be suggested to you as an autocomplete option:

[image: autocomplete]
 <sup>autocomplete suggestions for `\foo`</sup>

Comment: Similar features are available for auctex in emacs.

Comment: Yes, TeXstudio has Auto-Correct (“Macros”) but you have to feed it manually.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You mean you can program it to replace `\foornote` with `\footnote`? I guess that counts, yeah. I think MS Word’s replacement mechanism also relies on a hard-coded list of common typos. Why don’t you add an answer about TeXstudio’s macros?