# Where does TeXstudio store the .cwl files for hyperref and xspace?

Tags: macros, hyperref, texstudio, auto-completion, xspace

TeXstudio uses .cwl files for storing information about which macros are defined by which packages, one file per package. This information is used for [autocompletion suggestions and highlighting of unrecognized macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110538/4012). Most of these files I can find in `C:\Users\doncherry\AppData\Roaming\texstudio`.

For some packages, e.g. `hyperref` and `xspace`, however, I can’t find them in that directory and neither in the program’s directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio`. Where are they hiding? Are they hard-coded into the executables?

Comment: xspace one is here it's not very interesting:-) http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/xspace.cwl

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but I’d actually like to know where it is on my computer, so that I can add the missing `\xspaceaddexceptions` to it. For just looking at them, http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/ contains all the predefined .cwl files, I would hypothesize.

Comment: I know but google can't tell me that:-) (why I just made a comment rather than an answer:-)

Comment: @doncherry You could just add `\xspaceaddexceptions` to your own [costom `.cwl` file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79643/16595).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I know, but I’m just curious where those files are and if I can acces them `:)`.

Comment: Judging by an old post on [latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=10230) from one of the developers, they probably are stored in the `.exe`. Proposal: Copy both [`xspace.cwl`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/xspace.cwl) and [`hyperref.cwl`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/completion/hyperref.cwl) to the ``%APPDATA%\texstudio\`` folder and add the missing macros.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>Qrrbrbirlbel is exactly right:</strike>

> They probably are stored in the .exe. Proposal: Copy both xspace.cwl and hyperref.cwl to the %APPDATA%\texstudio\ folder and add the missing macros.

Entries in %APPDATA%\texstudio\ override the ones integrated in TeXstudio.

As of TeXstudio 2.10.8 the mechanism for searching cwl files has been refined.

TXS searches for cwl files in three different locations:

1. [settings-directory]/completion/user
2. builtin cwls
3. [settings-directory]/completion/autogenerated

See also [FAQ: Where are cwl files stored?](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-cwl-files-stored)

Also, I encourage you to share your updated cwl files, so we can integrate them for the next release. To do so, just create an entry in the [feature request tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/) and attach the files.

Comment: Thanks for the update! It’s great to have the information here as well.