# Is there an Autocorrect feature in TeXStudio 2.6.2?

Tags: macros, texstudio, auto-completion

I was wondering if there's an **Autocorrect** feature in TexStudio 2.6.2 that works like in MS Word so that if I have to type a certain word many times, the editor writes it for me as soon as I press spacebar after I finish typing the shortcut for that particular word. (Eg. phl --> photolithography)

I've already searched StackExchange for similar questions and read Qrrbrbirlbel's comment 
 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110534/are-there-any-editors-or-packages-with-auto-correct-for-latex-commands). I've tried my hand at the Macros but it's not working properly, maybe some bug that needs TeXStudio to re-start for it take action or maybe I simply don't know how to make it work. 
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Does autocompletion is enough for you? For example, I created a personal package containing my most used commands and now when I start to type it the editor completes to me.

Comment: Ok, never mind! After some err & try with the Macros, I finally got the knack of it. However I wonder if one can insert a case-sensitivity to the Trigger meaning that if I write `Phl` (instead of `phl`) this should yield `Photolithography`, with the capital P.

Answer (score 2):

From the Macros menu, go to "Edit Macros...". Add a new entry with the "Add" button then type in the specifics of your Macro. Give it a Name for your own ease of use, write the Trigger command (for eg. `phl`, short for photolithography), select among Normal/Environment/Script (Normal is ok here), then don't forget the crucial step: LaTeX code. In this case I'd type `photolithography`. Save and close. Then try out your macro, see if it works by writing a couple of sentences that have the trigger word `phl` and you'll see the Editor replacing it almost immediately with `photolithography`.

Answer (score 1):

If the completion engine (cwl files) or simple macros aren't enough for you, have a look at [this scripting example](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#word-completion). It's quite straight forward to extend this to case insensitive matching.