# Formal Writing Style Correction on Latex

Tags: spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to perform advanced spell checking of latex documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-perform-advanced-spell-checking-of-latex-documents)

Microsoft Word has a nifty property of style correction, where it can find phrasal verbs, passive voice and things that usually are not suitable for scientific writing.

Is there any editor that support this for latex?

Comment: A list of them can be found at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://goo.gl/3f1mL).

Comment: Yup, not one of them seem to have style correction

Comment: This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-perform-advanced-spell-checking-of-latex-documents. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please clarify what your looking for beyond that other question. (Possibly also interesting, but not a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex)

Comment: Yes they are very similar, I had read the second one, I just wondered whether any integrated editor had the same features implemented without the need of external software. 
Also, one of the is Linux only, and right now I'm bounded to a windows computer.
If you find it too similar, feel free to close it, thanks.