# Any LaTeX editor with grammar check capability?

Tags: editors

Is there any LaTeX editor with built-in grammar check? I was writing my thesis and was just wondering; it could be very helpful.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex

Comment: What kind of grammar: English grammar (or that of some other human language), or TeX/LaTeX grammar?

Comment: English grammar.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Oh... Yeah thanks ... will keep that in mind from now on ...

Comment: For French, I use [Antidote](http://www.druide.com/antidote.html), which integrates with most software. It has now support to check grammar etc. in LaTeX files without breaking the source code. Would be interested in a similar tool for english, too...

Comment: Grammar check or spelling check?

Comment: @mario S E - Grammar check

Comment: Duplicate? : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-perform-advanced-spell-checking-of-latex-documents