# A list of spelling errors in multiple .tex files

Tags: spelling

I do have a large PDF document created based on 10 different .tex files. Im using Mac and I want to spell check these words such a way that I can get list of incorrect words (e.g., by using a shell command, or a tool). How can I do that?

Comment: The answers to these questions might be helpful for you: [How to perform advanced spell checking of latex documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385/5245), [Spell checking LaTeX documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15/5245)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an editor that has a build-in spell checker. [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) will check your spelling while ignoring formatting, however it's not a free app ($10).

[How to perform advanced spell checking of latex documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-to-perform-advanced-spell-checking-of-latex-documents?rq=1) describes how you can strip the formatting for spell checking in Text Edit, for a free solution.