# Spelling mistake detector for LaTeX/PDF

Tags: spelling, proofreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spell checking LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents)

I have a LaTeX file which I use to generate a PDF. 
Is there any tool which I can use to detect spelling mistakes, either directly in the .tex file or in the pdf file ?

Comment: What editor are you using? Winedt has a spellchecker that ignores TeX syntax.

Comment: I think Prakashkumar is looking for a "latex" answer, i.e. some kind of package that will 'typeset' that certain words are misspelled in the produced PDF. Some time ago I did something like that just for fun but using an external program that generated an auxiliary tex source file marking (e.g. with red) misspelled words and even giving suggestions as a PDF-ballon-comment. The script was using hunspell or aspell internally but was not integrated with LaTeX at all. I would be interested in something like that also. Interpreted in this way I think this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I think `apsell` does the trick for me. I use VI to edit my LaTeX documents. So, I wanted a tool to check for spelling mistakes rather than going through the entire document manually.

Comment: The vim-latex plugin allows you to use vim's spell checking in a latex document.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Aspell](http://aspell.net/) has a special mode to check TeX and so also LaTeX files.

```
$ aspell -c -t some.tex
```

Also, your LaTeX editor might already include a special spell checking mode for LaTeX sources, e.g emacs' flyspell comes with options to check LaTeX sources. Emacs is the framework (haha) behind the excellent AucTeX TeX environment.

Comment: When I try `aspell -t temp.tex` , it gives me `Error: Unknown Action: temp.tex` . Any obvious mistake I am making ?

Comment: @Prakashkumar Thiagarajan - You need to specify an action, e.g. `aspell -t -c temp.tex` to "check" a file.

Answer (score 3):

Three basic options:

1. You can use [aspell](http://aspell.net/) or [ispell](http://www.gnu.org/software/ispell/), which are LaTeX aware spell-checkers.
2. Use an editor like [LyX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LyX), which has built in spell-checking.
3. Output your [text to plain-text using detex](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#Convert_to_plain_text), and then spell-check that with whatever you like (e.g. OpenOffice).