# Spell check for miktex

Tags: spelling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spell checking LaTeX documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents)

I have MiKTeX installed on my laptop running windows 7. I did some searching around google for spell checking documents in MiKTeX and I came across 4Spell. Unfortunately the links to this tool are broken. I'm wondering what options are available to me? Most solutions I have found seem to be for linux/unix environments. I also tried the 'detex' command in a command prompt, but this just displays a message saying that 'detex' is not recognised as a command.

Comment: Have a look at [spell checking latex documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents)

Comment: I'm closing a duplicate: the top answer in the duplicate ('This is the job of the editor') applies whatever platform you use.