# Integrating external dictionaries with Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

I'm a relatively new LaTeX user and I want to know:

1. Is there a way to link an external dictionary to LaTeX and
2. what dictionaries are recommended?

Comment: What about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents?

Answer (score 8):

In the link of @Thorsten I couldn't find anything about Texmaker, and about particularities so:

1. In general, all you need is `*.aff` and `*.dic` file, you can download them from OpenOffice dictionary packages (archive contains these and some other files)
   e.g. `en_GB.aff` and `en_GB.dic` placed in right directory does the trick.
2. Dictionaries of the languages that you will be using.

For Texmaker specifically, you go:
Options -> Configure Texmaker -> Spelling Dictionary

Maybe this should be a comment but I'm so far able to answer and not to comment.