# Add word to TexMaker dictionary?

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

How can I add a word to the dictionary of TexMaker? I cannot see any options for this in the software.

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53233/13034) about adding external dictionaries to Texmaker may be helpful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If adding is what you just need then this answer might work for you. If you want to install a new dictionary, follow the link in the comment. With your terminal, `cd` to the directory of your `TeXMaker` dictionary. If you don't know where, in `TeXMaker` click

> Options > Configure TeXMaker > Editor

You can see the directory of the dictionary in the option `Spelling dictionary`. In Ubuntu, once you are in the directory, type

```
sudo gedit en_GB.dic
```

and put the word you want to add in there.

In Windows, just go to the directory and double click on the file or open with `Notepad`. Then write the word you want to add.

You might also want to save the customized file in another folder and have your `Spelling dictionary` option point to the custom file.

Comment: thanks, that is a very long way round to add words to a dictionary. I can't believe they haven't got this functionality in built. Thanks anyway, that will have to do for now I guess.

Comment: Just FYI, the fork `TeXStudio` has a tool called `Thesaurus` that you can use to add words to the dictionary. I haven't been using it as often as before though.

Comment: Just to add a useful bit of info for Windows users: the dictionary files are in the base folder of the TexMaker installation and need to be opened with Administrator privileges.

Comment: @fgphost Not only it is a long way around. Almost two years later this is still the state of the art. Per project dictionaries would be really comfortable.

Comment: It's now been more than 8 years... Also, you can add words to the dictionary this way but you have to repsect the alphabetical ordering, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 28):

In the newer versions they have also added a "Spell check" feature (Control + Shift + F7 ; or from the menu: Edit > Check Spelling) which allows you to add new words by clicking "always ignore".

The custom words are stored in `$HOME/.config/xm1/texmaker.ini` (unix) or in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\xm1` (windows)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Great key, since the feature seems not to be accessible from the menu

Comment: Great, now they only have to add that option to the context menu as well, and I can die happy. Still a better workaround than manually editing the dict, thanks!

Comment: Just to add, the custom words are added to the texmaker.ini after you close the program. On windows, the path is C:\Users\\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\xm1. It seems that you can also add a list of words separated by comma on the line Spell\Words="ignorethisword,ignoremealso"

Comment: Now you can also do it from the menu: Edit > Check Spelling. Note that it starts from the cursor, not from the beginning of the document. @magnattic you can die happy.

Comment: I have the impression that "always ignore" is forgotten as soon as you close the Check Spelling window.

Answer (score 13):

In version 4.1.1, you can right click a word underlined in red and then click "Check Spelling Selection". That will open a dialog box where you need to click "Always Ignore".

Comment: In version 4.5 one can also place the cursor in a position without red underlining, select "Tools" then "Check Spelling", for the entire document including use of the "Always Ignore" option when desired.

Comment: This should be now the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I've been doing. Unfortunately though "Always ignore" is not the same adding a word in the dictionnary: if i misspel a word that TexMaker has learned to ignore, it will not offer to correct it.

Comment: @Andrea's point is good. Also, sometimes I have mistakenly pressed on "always ignore" and now I have no idea how to delete the "wrong" word from the list of words that should actually be ignored.