# How can one mount a Scientific dictionary to TexMaker?

Tags: spelling, dictionaries

I do an awful lot of lab reports in `\LaTeX`, It is fantastic but one thing i have always struggled with is spelling I currently have a scientific dictionary custom_scientific_UK.dic however I am having trouble getting it TexMaker to use it. I imagine I'm not the only one who has had this issue anyone get a solution?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Have you read this question? :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84463/add-word-to-texmaker-dictionary/84476#84476

Comment: I have seen that however whenever I mount my dictionary in that manner it corrects nothing and there are no redlines even when I intentionally misspell words. It is more than likely due to my dictionary simply not working would you happen to have come across better custom dictionaries ?