# Ignoring arguments of label, ref etc. for spell checking in TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, spelling

It is well-known that the argument of certain commands (`label`, `ref`, `cite` are typical examples) almost never make any sense in LaTeX, and should be hence avoided when spell checking is performed.

I have found examples for environments where it is not working ([TeXMaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62646/make-spellchecker-ignore-contents-of-certain-commands-in-texmaker)), and instances where it seems to work ([kile](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221370), [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/spelling.html)).

However, I simply wasn't able to get any information about this problem in TeXnicCenter!

So the question is: is it somehow possible to perform spell checking in TeXnicCenter with the arguments of these commands ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your preferences by going to Tools/options/spelling and then you'll find some checkboxes and select the ones you want to ignore.

The menu looks like this:

[image]

For more information on these options and others, please visit the TeXnic Center's *options* [documentation](http://texniccenter.sourceforge.net/options.html)

However, please bear in mind that ---as stated in the documentation---, **the argument of the command is always spell-checked**, and not the command itself.

Furthermore, if you wish to include this feature for specific commands (such as `\label` and `\ref`) in future TeXnicCenter versions, please add your recommendation in the [TeXnicCenter Feature Request Page](http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/feature-requests/)

Nevertheless, there is kind of a workaround: as you can see in the picture attached, you can ignore things with numbers and/or uppercase... so you can always use numbers and/or uppercase for the arguments of `\label` and `\ref` and `\cite`.

Comment: Would you add a screen shot?

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. The values in `\begin{}` and `\end{}`, for example, are still marked as a spelling error. Or self defined node names in `TikZ` pictures. Or `\label{}`. But I think this can only be fixed by the author of the program in a new release.

Comment: Well, I did exactly this, but it didn't help at all (not even for label, ref etc.!): http://i.imgur.com/dATPqwb.jpg

Comment: As stated in the documentation (see link in answer), the argument of the command is always spell-checked, it is the command itself that is not

Comment: That's exactly my problem! That is not logical. The command itself is avoided (which is good!), but I think the argument should also be ignored! (As it is done in many other cases as well, see the examples I linked.)

Comment: Well @TamasFerenci, I think that depends how you see it.  For example, wouldn't you like your argument in a `\caption`, `\section`, `\title`, etc. to be spell checked?

Comment: But checking `\ref` and `\label` doesn't make much sense, because it will always be "gibberish" (according to a spell checker).

Comment: I agrre with you @FooBar, but I think that'll have to be something to `feature request` for the next version. I'm updating my answer to include what we just talked

Comment: @Mario S. E.: Sure! But not the argument of label, ref and cite. These should be handled separately, and the arguments of the latter should be avoided. This would be logical in my opinion!

Comment: @MarioS.E. I took the liberty of highlighting the part of your answer that directly answers the question asked.

Comment: Yes, that highlighted part is the actual answer to my question. At least if this implies that there is not even a workaround to this problem. (I.e. it is not only impossible through the Options/Spelling, but it is impossible generally.)If so, I'll accept this answer (and I have posted a feature request as well, as you suggested).

Comment: @TamasFerenci, well, there is kind of a workaround: as you can see in the picture attached, you can ignore things with numbers and/or uppercase... so you can always use numbers and/or uppercase for the arguments of `\label` and `\ref` and `\cite`

Comment: @Mario S. E., that's a good idea indeed! I haven't thought of that, despite the fact that it is absolutely logical. Although... I'd prefer not using numbers or uppercases only as labels, but I accept that this is the best that we can do right now. I've uploaded a feature request (as you suggested), and I accept your answer!