# How to get the icon for spell-checking the generated PDF in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker, spelling

In this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62659/170518) it is suggested that Texmaker has a spellcheck option for the generated PDF. It looks like this:

[image: PDF spell check option (ABC icon)]

But mine doesn't have this option available:

[image: PDF spell check option (ABC icon) missing]

How can I activate it?