# Spell checking LaTeX documents in Windows

Tags: tools, spelling

I'm looking for a spell checking software for LaTeX in Windows. I know that such questions [have been asked before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15/spell-checking-latex-documents) but more than a decade has passed. Hopefully, there are better solutions out now. Aspell was last compiled in 2002 for Windows and out of support.

My LaTeX documents have a lot of math involved so I'd like the software to skip the formulae.

Comment: What editor for `.tex` are you using?

Comment: @SimonDispa Sublime Text.

Comment: TexmicCenter doesn't ignore formulae, but it does ignore single letters.  So use `$c x$` instead of `$cx$` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

Use the *LTeX – LanguageTool grammar/spell checking* extension in *Microsoft Visual Studio Code*.

**Detailed instructions**

1. Install [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
2. Install the extension.

[image]

3. Restart VS Code and open your tex file in it. Under problems you will see some potential errors, here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can use [Grammarly](https://grammarly.com) in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Grammarly extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly).

[image]

After installing the extension, one has to add LaTeX files to the list of files for which Grammarly should be activated, as described in the extension instructions. Then LaTeX documents will have grammar corrections as follows.

[image]